# How can i get items values from xml result swift

Tags: swift, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser, swifty-json

I have the xml result below, how can i parse it and get Fields's values? Please help

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no' ?>
<ATBResponse command="get" result="success">      

<Record table="User" partial="true">
    <Field name="accountID" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[family_1]]></Field>
    <Field name="userID" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[brat_peet]]></Field>      
</Record>
<Record table="User" partial="true">
    <Field name="accountID" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[family_1]]></Field>
    <Field name="userID" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[Miketyson]]></Field>

</Record>
<Record table="User" partial="true">
    <Field name="accountID" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[family_1]]></Field>
    <Field name="userID" primaryKey="true"><![CDATA[Kennedy]]></Field>      
</Record>
</ATBResponse>
```

I have the xml result below, how can i parse it and get Fields's values like this?

```
let account = "family_1"
let users = "brat_peet" , "Miketyson" , "Kennedy"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do parsing.

You might want to :

- Use the NSXMLParser class provided by Apple ;
- Create your own XML parse class / methods ;
- Use an existing library to parse XML.

For the last option, you can give a look at the following : https://github.com/Wolg/awesome-swift#jsonxml-manipulation (SWXMLHash)

Comment: For the last option, i can't see where can i execute this : $ gem install cocoapods --pre ?????

Comment: This is the command line you can use to install the dependence through `CocoaPods`. If you're not familiar with that, you can simply take the `SWXMLHash.swift` file ( http://goo.gl/kRPUdP ) and add it to your project. Then you can start with `let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)` (where `data` is either a `NSData` or `String` of the xml you want to parse). Then, look at the given example on the website to access the xml tags and values.

Comment: i don't have more problem with SWXMLHash.swift, it's works. But i was trying to use the example given on the website, until now now i can't. I updated the xml result. Could you help me to field values please?